# intonation resolving apparent contradiction

Tags: meaning-in-context, intonation

Is it natural to use (a) to mean (b)? If it is, does it require special intonation?

> a. Jack is not a dog but a Labrador.

> b. Jack is not just any dog but a Labrador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not natural. It sounds like the speaker doesn't know that a Labrador is a type of dog, regardless of intonation.

A natural way of structuring this would be:

> Jack is not a dog. Jack's a Labrador.

And yes, it would require intonation to make the point that you know a Labrador is actually a type of dog.

Another aspect that doesn't work is that being a Labrador would have to be generally understood as very impressive. It's much easier to be understood with something like this:

> It's not a car. It's a *Ferrari*.

Comment: Are you saying the logical issue is somehow safely ignored if the OP sentence is broken into two?

Comment: @Apollyon Somehow, yes.

Answer (score 1):

(b) is fine but (a) is very strange. (a) would only work if the "but a ___" part were something that is not a subset of the leading portion.

Comment: Thank you. What dialect of English do you speak natively?

Comment: I agree in general, but I could maybe see using form (a) if the intonation were something to suggest that saying "a dog" were somehow considered shocking or grossly improper, e.g. "Hey, you have a dog" - "'A dog'?  Jack is not *'a dog'*, he is a prize-winning champion Labrador, descendant of eight generations of champions!"

Comment: @Apollyon: AME (western US if the region makes a difference, though I don't believe so in this case).